# Unusual inactivity of an "Not An Answer" flag

Tags: support, flags, not-an-answer

I reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27983184/3041194) in the [first posts queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7045789) about 21 hours ago.

I was wondering *to myself* why the answer was still undeleted, and my flag of Not An Answer on it is still showing as "active". It seems like a clear-cut NAA, so it confused me as to why no other action appears to have been taken on this after 21 hours. So I did some further research.

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/203969/find-the-reviewtasks-for-a-post?postid=27983184) shows my review I did yesterday on it. However, I'm wondering why it doesn't show any *Low Quality Posts* reviews on it yesterday?

Is there any reason why my NAA flag on it wouldn't send it to the *Low Quality Posts* queue?

Something just seems a little off with this to me. Did something go wrong somewhere in the process, or is there some reason that a flagged NAA from the *First Posts* queue wouldn't end up in the *Low Quality Posts* queue?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The answer in fact appeared in *three* review queues:

- [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7045789)
- [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6761193)
- [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6761251)

Somehow the user figured out that something wasn't right, and they [deleted and undeleted their answer repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27983184/revisions) either to shake off the flags or the downvotes.  Guess which one they managed to shake off.

FYI:

> The VLQ and NAA flags can only ever push a post into the LQP queue once. Which they did. There were two NAA flags on it before the OP's delete/undelete run, and a review task was created. The deletions invalidated it by marking all the flags as helpful (so it was removed because it no longer matched any criteria for being in that queue). That action prevents it from ever getting back into the queue - all further flags would require a moderator to process. - [animuson ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) - [src](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286093/unusual-inactivity-of-naa-flag#comment155527_286094)

Comment: I see the Late Answers and Low Quality Posts reviews were from January 16th though. My first posts review was on February 14th (yesterday) (when I flagged it as NAA). He did the undeleting/deleting of his post on January 16th.

Comment: @bluet - You flagged that post on a Saturday that was also a U.S. holiday. I'm guessing that not as many people were around to review or act on it.

Comment: @bluet The VLQ and NAA flags can only ever push a post into the LQP queue *once*. Which they did. There were two NAA flags on it before the OP's delete/undelete run, and a review task was created. The deletions invalidated it by marking all the flags as helpful (so it was removed because it no longer matched any criteria for being in that queue). That action prevents it from ever getting *back* into the queue - all further flags would require a moderator to process.

Comment: Whoa, is this a loophole that is frequently exploited?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: I believe most users who do this are completely unaware of flags, because this usually happens with new users. It seems to be more of a reaction to downvotes than anything - why, I don't know, but that's just how it seems. Normally, posts that are undeleted by the author after being deleted by review will be flagged by the system for our attention as disputed reviews, but in this case the user deleted the post themselves.

Comment: This "loophole" not only exists in the form of un-deleting but also copy-delete-paste.  I most frequently use it to get around the 5 minute edit limit on comments.  Why?  Because my spelling is that bad. : )

Comment: @CandiedOrange are you saying that a user may copy their "NAA" answer, delete it, and then paste it into a new answer and submit a new answer that is the same as the deleted one? That's no loophole really, since the deleted answer will count against them in the algorithm for a possible answer ban.

Comment: @bluet I am not privy to the inner workings of any answer ban algorithm.  I would hope, since abuse is possible with both methods, that it considers both.  However, in the past I have legitimately deleted my own answer and supplied a new answer.  So however the algorithm works it has to decide what qualifies as "new" or it becomes either ineffective or draconian.