# NaA flag deleted by edit in low quality review?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer

The [post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32064089/203657) clearly is not an answer (even confirmed by the author in a comment). I flagged it yesterday, and see the flag marked as helpful but the post not deleted.

Looking at its edit history:

- it reached the low quality queue
- [got edited](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9211878) by a reviewer
- the edit was rolled-back by OP

(not sure whether the last makes any difference).

Wondering if this is intended behaviour? And what to do next - flag again?

Comment: see [Edits shouldn't dismiss “not an answer” flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252854/165773) at MSE

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286093/unusual-inactivity-of-an-not-an-answer-flag